# Creating new user with Laravel 5.2 authentication

Tags: php, forms, authentication, laravel-5

i'm new in the laravel framework and I'm facing some difficulties in pass some variables from a form to a function.

I'm looking the guide: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication and I don't know how pass the variables to the function.

I want to know how the variables are passed to another methods, because I can't access the function to create a new user, so When I submit the form, I want to go to the create function.

Anyone knows how the authentication works?

Here are my files

**routes.php**

```
Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('user/new', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('user/new', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

Route::controllers([
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

**AuthController.php**

```
protected function create(array $data){
        print_r($data);
        /*
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        */
    }
```

**register.blade.php**

```
<!-- resources/views/auth/register.blade.php -->

@extends('layout.master_layout')

@section('content')
    <form method="POST" action="/usuario/novo">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}

        <div class="card-panel">
            <h5>Personal information</h5>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l7">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                    {{ Form::text('','',array('id' => 'first_name',
                                              'type' => 'text')) }}
                    {{ Form::label('First name') }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12">

                {{ Form::button('Create new user', array('class' => 'btn waves-effect waves-light', 'type'  => 'submit', 
                       'name'  => 'action')) }}

            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
@endsection
```

Comment: the create function will add the new user to database and return that same user object to the login method (you can't see it beceause its in another file) so the user will be logged in after being created, can you explain what you want to do exactly? if you want to change the fields  EX: name to first name , just change this 'name' => $data['name'],
             with this `'first_name' => $data['first_name'],` if you want to access the authenticated user in another class use `Auth::user()-fiest_name`

Comment: I can't access the create function because I don't know how to redirect the form to this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this in your form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('user/new')}}
```

have the same fields in the form and controller